# Get values of multiple inputs

Tags: php, post, input

```
<input name="movie" value="1" />
<input name="movie" value="2" />
<input name="movie" value="3" />
<input name="movie" value="4" />
<input name="movie" value="5" />
```

**How do I get values of all these inputs by `$_POST`?**

I can not use an unique name for each `<input>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In HTML do something like this:

```
<input name="movie[]" value="1" />
<input name="movie[]" value="2" />
<input name="movie[]" value="3" />
<input name="movie[]" value="4" />
<input name="movie[]" value="5" />
```

In PHP do something like this:

```
$movies = $_POST['movie'];
foreach($movies as $movie){
   echo $movie . "<br />"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `name="movie[]"`